# How to use ABS function in ElasticSearch equery?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch version 5.1.

I'm trying to retrieve all documents, where the subtraction of two fields < |X|

Here is the query that I run:

```
post /my_idx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc[\"f1\"].value - doc[\"f2\"].value < 9 && doc[\"f1\"].value - doc[\"f2\"].value > -9",
            "lang": "painless"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I tried using the common mathematic function 'abs' without success.

How can I use this function in my query?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use `Math.abs(...)` method in `painless` scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can try scripting using `groovy` lang which has `abs` function.

```
 {
 "query": {
 "bool": {
  "must": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['f1'].value - doc['f2'].value  < Math.abs(9)",
        "lang": "groovy"
         }
        }
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,

According to Elastic search:

Deprecated in 5.0.0., 
Groovy will be replaced by the new scripting language Painless

Comment: Thanks for this info.